# Using STTwitter Library how can I attach an image

Tags: ios, post, sttwitter

I'm kind of new on objective c, and I'm trying to do a twitter client. I'm using the STTwitter API.  I'm using the for tweeting the method :

```
[twitter postStatusUpdate:twitterPostTweetText
               inReplyToStatusID:nil
                        mediaURL:_twitterPostMediaURL
                         placeID:nil
                        latitude:latitud
                       longitude:longitud
                    successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {

                        self->twitterPostTweetText = @"";
                        self->twitterPostTweetStatus = @"OK";
                        self->latitud = nil;
                        self->longitud = nil;
                        self.twitterPostMediaURL = nil;
                    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                        self->twitterPostTweetStatus = error ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown error";
                    }];
```

but it says that for sending an image attached I have to use NSUrl but I can't figure out how does it work.  I want to send an image that I take with the camera roll.
Please, any ideas?

Comment: Your English is fine but you neglected to post any code or say what you've tried and what's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `NSURL` instance representing the file path.

See the example in STTwitter demo https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/demo_osx/STTwitterDemoOSX/STClientVC.m#L33-L48